# Magnifier glass for text

Tags: looking-for-a-script, text

I've seen scripts that allow you to zoom images, i want to do the same for text, is this possible?

Like onmouseover or hover it zooms images. i want it for text! is it possible?

Comment: You're not describing what you want very well; there's more detail necessary. Can you provide a link to what you're referring to as far as the image example? This could be interpreted as anything from a simple image expander, to a fisheye menu.

Answer (score 1):

In at least Firefox & Chrome you can make the text within a block bigger by using the `:hover` syntax.  Apparently this only works for links in IE. Here's an example:

**html**:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>magnifying glass example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="mag.css" />
</head>
<body>
This text will not magnify.
<div class="magnifiable">
This text can be magnified.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**mag.css**:

```
body { color: black; }
div.magnifiable { color: red; }
div.magnifiable:hover { font-size: 200%; }
```

Comment: Just a note, :hover only works for links in IE6.

Comment: @Jamie Schembri:  Answer edited to reflect the browser dependencies I'm aware of.